# Javascript ajax fill issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a module and have copied the formatting off other pages but it does not seem to work.  Is is meant to get the value from House Location and create a page slug in the box underneath.  The Form class is crud and I can't get any error with Firebug.

**Controller Function:**

```
function stream_slug()
{
    $this->load->helper('text');

    $this->output->set_output( url_title($this->input->post('location'), 'underscore', TRUE) );
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="location">House Location:</label> <input type="text" name="location" value="" maxlength="250" /><span class="required-icon tooltip">Required</span></li> 

<li class="even"> 
<label for="slug">House Slug</label> 
<input type="text" name="slug" value="" maxlength="60" /><span class="required-icon tooltip">Required</span> 
</li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){

        form = $('form.crud');

        $('input[name="location"]', form).keyup($.debounce(300, function(){

            slug = $('input[name="slug"]', form);

            $.post(BASE_URI + 'index.php/admin/sales/stream_slug', { title : $(this).val() }, function(new_slug){
                slug.val( new_slug );
            });
        }));

    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Updated jQuery:**

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){

        form = $('form.crud');

        form.find('input[name="location"]', form).keyup($.debounce(function(){

            slug = $('input[name="slug"]', form);

            $.ajax(BASE_URI + 'index.php/admin/sales/stream_slug', { title : $(this).val() }, function(new_slug){
                slug.val( new_slug );
            });
        }, 300));

    });
})(jQuery);
```

**debounce:**

```
/*
 * jQuery throttle / debounce - v1.1 - 3/7/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);
```

Comment: Check out this example, it uses jsfiddle's HTML post-back to simulate the AJAX interaction: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EgrJF/

Comment: Do I disable/remove the dbounce file?  I am still getting that error and I have tried the full file

Comment: Compare what you're doing with the jsfiddle.net example (which works).

Comment: I copied and pasted the js the html looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you have the arguments for [`$.debounce`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/) backwards:

```
$.debounce(fn, timeout, [invokeAsap], [ctx]);
```

Try using:

```
$('input[name="location"]', form).keyup($.debounce(function() {
    //...
}, 300));
```

I'd also suggest that you switch from

```
$('input[name="location"]', form)
```

to

```
from.find('input[name="location"]')
```

so that the `form` doesn't get visually lost at the right side but this is just a stylistic issue and subject to personal preference (unlike the argument order of external APIs).

Comment: @Jess: Any errors in the console? Is the PHP getting called? Any errors on the server logs? You do have a `<form class="crud">` around that HTML too, right?

Comment: @Jess: Does it work without the `debounce`? Have you tried with `$.ajax` so that you can use an error callback too?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), there are some examples in there. Your current callback would become the `success` callback and you'd add an `error` callback to see if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand

Comment: `$.post` is just a wrapper for `$.ajax`, if you switch to `$.ajax` you'll have access to an error callback as well as the success callback, the error callback might tell you something useful.

Comment: I have now got an error by changing post its j.apply is not a function @ debounce.js:9

Comment: Did you fix the argument order? You might want to use the non-minified version of debounce for debugging.